# selecting room type on room availability subquery

Tags: sql

table reserve

- reserve_id
- roominv_id
- chckin
- chckout
- status (reserved,canceled,pending)

table roominventory

- roominv_id
- room_id
- room_number
- room_status(available , unavailable)

table room

- room_id
- room_type

I'm doing a room reservation system.

I already have the query for the date availability of the rooms :

```
SELECT r.roominv_id,r.room_id 
FROM roominventory r
WHERE r.roominv_id
NOT IN 
(SELECT b.roominv_id
FROM reserve b
WHERE NOT (b.chckout < '$chckin'
OR
b.chckin > '$chckout'))
```

My question is, where will I insert the condition in my query, where I can select a specific room type depends on the room availability.

I know it is like `room.room_type LIKE '%$roomtype%'` but I don't know which part of the query I will insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the table `room` like this:

```
SELECT 
  r.roominv_id, 
  r.room_id 
FROM roominventory AS r
INNER JOIN room AS m ON m.room_id = r.room_id
WHERE m.room_type LIKE '%$roomtype%'
  AND r.roominv_id NOT IN (SELECT b.roominv_id
                           FROM reserve b
                           WHERE NOT (b.chckout < '$chckin'
                                      OR 
                                      b.chckin > '$chckout'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach using `LEFT JOIN` and checking for `NULL`:

```
SELECT 
  r.roominv_id, 
  r.room_id 
FROM roominventory AS r
    INNER JOIN room AS m ON m.room_id = r.room_id
    LEFT JOIN reserve res ON r.roominv_id = res.roominv_id AND
               NOT (b.chckout < '$chckin' OR b.chckin > '$chckout')
WHERE m.room_type LIKE '%$roomtype%' 
    AND res.roominv_id IS NULL
```

Good luck.